# I cannot deploy a war file with Glassfish

Tags: path, null, glassfish, archive

I'm now trying to upload a war file to a local Glassfish server. But I'm always getting this message:
GUI internal error: Archive Path is NULL
[image]
I read some users who had the same problem and the suggested solution was to change the content of a file named uploadFrame.jsf.
I couldn't even find that file. Can anyone help me out on this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: **uploadFrame.jsf** is a file within the source of Glassfish. If you [download and unzip **ee8-oss-sources.zip**](https://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0/release/index.html) you can find it in directory **\ee8-oss-product-bundle\glassfish-5.0\appserver\admingui\common\src\main\resources\applications**. See [Can´t deploy applications from Web Console](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22739) for more details. It doesn't look like there is any planned fix for the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Have same problem (v 5.0).

Only autodeploy works: move EAR/WAR to `glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue with GUI internal error: Archive Path is NULL. With the last version of Glassfish 5.0.1, but after change my server to stable version glassfish.-5.0. The issue is solved successfully. I Hope you solve your problem with the version of glassfish.

Comment: I just ran into this trying to follow the tutorial with glassfish 5.1.0. The fileChooser.jsf for the local packaged file or directory was also quirky, file selection didn't seem to work, but if you paste in the path to the file it worked. Deploy from the command line works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that can be found on the web. You edit the "**uploadFrame.jsf**" file in the Glassfish "**console-common.jar**".

The original line of code in "uploadFrame.jsf":

```
<sun:form id="form">
```

The new line of code:

```
<sun:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Remember to stop and restart your Glassfish Server after the change has been made. More detailed information is in these links below:

- [From "**Glassfish Issues**" on Github](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22739#issuecomment-621965272)
- [A Step-By-Step Video On YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWFrylN_Uuk)